# Function name of wrapped function?

Tags: python

How can I get the name of the original function?

```
def wrap(f):
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something
    return wrapped_f

@wrap
def A(params):
   # do something

print(A.__name__)
```

result: wrapped_f, but I need A!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

Straight from the docs:

> Without the use of this decorator factory, the name of the example function would have been 'wrapper', and the docstring of the original example() would have been lost.

**Example:**

```
from functools import wraps


def wrap(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    return wrapped_f


@wrap
def A(params):
    pass


print(A.__name__)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
A
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) or update wrapped_f's `__name__` attribute manually.

```
from functools import wraps

def wrap(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something
    return wrapped_f

@wrap
def A(params):
   # do something

print(A.__name__)
```